# Tracing a position in a circle if the view is a square

Tags: java, android, math

So, I am making a cutom PieChartView and now I want to hilight the piece of the chart I clicked on, however I don't know how to detect which piece of the pie chart I clicked on since the whole View is actually a square. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Read up on polar and Cartesian coordinates, here: http://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html   You will need to convert between the two.

Comment: Thx im giving it a try now!

Answer (score 0):

Use `atan2` to convert the vector with respect to the center of the chart into an angle. Turning that angle into a piece of the pie should be simple, but depends on how you represent your pie.